# SDL2, FnMut and mpsc, sender can not be shared safely between threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, sdl-2

I want to start a timer with `sdl2-rs` crate for performing draw calls. I wanted to start it by doing something like this:

```
extern crate sdl2;

use std::sync::mpsc;

enum Event {
    Draw,
}

fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
    video_subsystem.gl_attr().set_context_version(4, 5);
    println!(
        "Current gl version: {:?}",
        video_subsystem.gl_attr().context_version()
    );
    let timer_subsystem = sdl_context.timer().unwrap();

    let window = video_subsystem
        .window("rust-sdl2 demo: Video", 800, 600)
        .position_centered()
        .opengl()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let context = window.gl_create_context().unwrap();

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    {
        let timer_tx = tx.clone();
        timer_subsystem.add_timer(
            1000u32 / 120u32,
            Box::new(move || {
                timer_tx.send(Event::Draw);
                1000u32 / 120u32
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `[closure@src/main.rs:33:22: 36:14 timer_tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>]`
  --> src/main.rs:33:13
   |
33 | /             Box::new(move || {
34 | |                 timer_tx.send(Event::Draw);
35 | |                 1000u32 / 120u32
36 | |             }),
   | |______________^ `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `[closure@src/main.rs:33:22: 36:14 timer_tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>]`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:33:22: 36:14 timer_tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Event>]`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::ops::FnMut() -> u32 + std::marker::Sync`
```

I understand that the sender is not `Sync` so I clone it and move cloned object into the `FnMut` closure but it does not work anyway. How can I do that? As from what I understand by moving the object into a closure we **don't** share it so it must work this way. Also, examples in the documentation say the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cloned sender has the same type as original sender, so it is still not `Sync`. `add_timer` function wants a closure which is `Sync`, so you need to wrap sender in `Mutex` which makes your sender safe to share between threads.

```
let timer_tx = Mutex::new(tx.clone());
timer_subsystem.add_timer(
    1000u32 / 120u32,
    Box::new(move || {
        timer_tx.lock().unwrap().send(Event::Draw);
        1000u32 / 120u32
    }),
);
```

Comment: This is correct, however, I don't need sync in the case of cloning - I use separate object and I think I have nothing to share. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: It is the function `add_timer` which needs `Sync`, not you. You have to comply with the requirement.